# Scala why _ (underscore) is working for first argument but not second

Tags: scala

I am learning scala, and I am not able to understand following thing.

why following works?

```scala
val colNames = List("salary_new", "age_new", "loc_new")
val colRenameMap = colNames.map(_ -> "a").toMap
```

but following doesn't ? is it, that I can use `_` as first argument only? how does this `_` works?

```scala
val colRenameMap = colNames.map(_ -> _.split("")).toMap
```

Comment: Each underscore refers to a new argument, so your second example is creating a function of two arguments, but you require a function of one argument. Try with a normal lambda instead: `x => x - > x.split("")`

Answer (score 1):

Luis answered the question already, so let's convert it to a proper answer.

```scala
val colRenameMap = colNames.map(_ -> _.split("")).toMap
```

translates to

```scala
val colRenameMap = colNames.map((a,b) => a -> b.split("")).toMap
```

Each time you use `_`, it refers to a *different* argument. Use it twice, and you get a function of two arguments, instead of the single-argument function `map` needs. In this case, you have to be explicit and name your unique argument to be able to use it twice

```scala
val colRenameMap = colNames.map(a => a -> a.split("")).toMap
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of in scala underscore in different cases means different sense.

first case:

```
val colNames = List("salary_new", "age_new", "loc_new")
val colRenameMap = colNames.map(_ -> "a").toMap
```

here you can rewrite line as follows:

```
val colRenameMap = colNames.map(x => x -> "a").toMap
```

if you are use argument in lambda expression once, you can concise expression by underscore `_`.

but when you try to use underscore `_` twice - it can't be used for that.

here you are trying to use argument in lamda expression twice:

```
                                   //first //second
val colRenameMap = colNames.map(x => x  ->  x.split("")).toMap
```

and you can't concise it using underscore `_`